# Check key press when OnTriggerStay() is called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an NPC that my player can talk to when the players collider is colliding with the NPC, I do that using this piece of code:

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "InteractiveArea")
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Debug.Log("PRESSED NPC");
            CreateAndShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this gets called really randomly, sometimes the first time I press "E", sometimes the second or third time, etc.

My rigidbodies:

[image]

[image]

The colliders I use are standard BoxCollider2D, my players collider is a trigger, the NPCs is not.

Why are some key press not detected in the `OnTriggerStay` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OnTriggerStay2D` is called randomly. This is why you should never check for Input inside of it.

Set to a flag to `true` and `false` in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` and `OnTriggerExit2D` functions then check for that flag and input in the `Update` function which is called every frame. Also, always use `CompareTag` instead of `other.gameObject.tag` to compare tags.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && triggerStay)
    {
        //
    }
}

bool triggerStay = false;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Entered");
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("InteractiveArea"))
    {
        triggerStay = true;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Exited");
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("InteractiveArea"))
    {
        triggerStay = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be because the value returned by [`Input.GetKeyDown` is only true for the single (`Update()`) frame that the key was pressed](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html), whereas physics (including `OnTriggerStay`) are called during *physics* frames, i.e. `FixedUpdate()`

Doing a bit of research I pull up [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/268326/ontriggerstay-execution-orderrate.html) which suggests:

> I've been struggling with this issue all afternoon!
>
> My OnTriggerStay and Update/FixedUpdate methods were not in sync resulting is split-second undesired effects.
>
> I finally found the solution when I read in the OnTriggerStay docs that this function can be a co-routine. I simply added a WaitForFixedUpdate in the correct location in my OnTriggerStay and it worked. They now both run in sync with each other. This even corrects the issue in Update.

[Another question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/887630/ontriggerstay-not-updating-every-frame.html) has this as a solution (Programmer's answer):

> OnTriggerStay will not call on every frame. One way to get around this is to have OnTriggerEnter, and OnTriggerExit set a bool. Then execute your code in the FixedUpdate().

While the documentation no longer says what [this post](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-often-is-ontriggerstay-called.89619/) says,

> OnTriggerStay gets called every FixedUpdate.
>
> *"Note: OnTriggerStay function is on the physics timer so it wont necessary run every frame. "*

That confirms my guess and that the documentation was changed to no longer include this note, for some unexplained reason.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this :

```
bool eIsOnclick;


 float wait = 0.03f;
    float nextFire = 0.0f;
void Update() {
   if(Input.GetKeyDown(keyKode.E))
      eIsOnclick = true;

else if(nextFire < Time.time)
    nextFire = Time.time + wait;
    ebas = false;

}
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision) {
   if(eIsOnclick == true) {
// your cods
}
```

// not work in alwaays aquestions

Comment: `ebas` is undefined