# How to get variable or call function from collider object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm writing an `OnTriggerStay(Collider other)` (in a ladder script) function to let a player climb a ladder and I want to know how to call a function (or access a variable) from the collided object.

I tried using the below solution but Unity tells me it is not valid in this context. Could someone suggest a solution?

```
myObject.GetComponent<MyScript>().MyFunction(); //wrong
```

Function

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) //Runs once per collider that is touching the player every frame
{

    if (other.CompareTag ("Player")) { //A player is touching the ladder

        //I want to get the isGrounded variable or getIsGrounded() function from other's playerScript.      

        if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") < 0) { // Player should go down
            other.transform.Translate (0, -.1f, 0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0) //Player should go up
                other.transform.Translate(0,.1f,0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to get the isGrounded variable or getIsGrounded() function from
>   other's playerScript.

The `Collider other` parameter from the `OnTriggerStay` function contains this information.

That should be: `other.GetComponent<MyScript>().getIsGrounded`

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) //Runs once per collider that is touching the player every frame
{

    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    { //A player is touching the ladder

        //I want to get the isGrounded variable or getIsGrounded() function from other's playerScript.     
        if(other.GetComponent<MyScript>().getIsGrounded)
        {

        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
        { // Player should go down
            other.transform.Translate(0, -.1f, 0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0) //Player should go up
            other.transform.Translate(0, .1f, 0);
    }

}
```

---

Note that if you want `OnTriggerStay` to be called every frame, I suggest you use the combination of `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` to accomplish this instead of `OnTriggerStay`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44684696/3785314) post of a full example.

Comment: Ok that works, but I want my ladder to hold my player hostage until they either fully ascend or descend. If I'm trying to descend the ladder and I'm walking backwards to it I'm going to fall off the ladder real fast so I was going to disable the script while climbing and !isGrounded.

Comment: Your current problem has nothing to do with your original question. Please create a new question for that problem.